# Sort html tables with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that works well when sorting html tables like this:

```
<table id="tableBeingDecomm" align="center" render-area="beingDecom">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th id="beingDecom"><a href="#">
                                    Server Name
                                    <img src='/icons/sort.png' width='20' height='20' style='display:inline;'>
                                </a></th>
                                <th id="beingDecomDate"><a href="#">
                                    Deleting Date
                                    <img src='/icons/sort.png' width='20' height='20' style='display:inline;'>
                                </a></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody render-action="loop">
                            <tr render-data="jsonBeingDecom">
                                <td>{!serverName!}</td>
                                <td>{!deletingDate!}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

but not with this new table below, no errors and the page becomes unresponsive:

```
<table id="PortsTable" align="center" render-area="dcPorts">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="ServerNameHeader1"><a href="#">
                            Server Name
                            <img src='/icons/sort.png' width='20' height='20' style='display:inline;'>
                        </a></th>
                        <th id="ServerNameHeader2"><a href="#">
                            Destination
                            <img src='/icons/sort.png' width='20' height='20' style='display:inline;'>
                        </a></th>
                        <th>Port 53</th>
                        <th>Port 88</th>
                        <th>Port 135</th>
                        <th>Port 139</th>
                        <th>Port 389</th>
                        <th>Port 445</th>
                        <th>Port 464</th>
                        <th>Port 636</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody render-action="loop">
                    <tr render-data="jsonPorts">
                        <td>{!Server Name!}</td>
                        <td>{!Destination!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 53!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 88!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 135!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 139!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 389!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 445!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 464!}</td>
                        <td>{!Port 636!}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and here is my code:

```
function sortTable(tableId, column) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";
    while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.rows;
      for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[column];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[column];
        if (!isNaN(x.innerHTML) && !isNaN(y.innerHTML)) {
          if (dir == "asc") {
            if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (dir == "asc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchcount ++;
      } else {
        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
          dir = "desc";
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  

let sortOrder = "asc";
```

The way I invoke the function is this:

document.getElementById("ServerNameHeader1").addEventListener("click", function() {
sortTable("PortsTable", 0);
});
document.getElementById("ServerNameHeader2").addEventListener("click", function() {
sortTable("PortsTable", 1);
});

I guess the function is running repeatedly, but I don't know why. The html structure is the same as the other tables

Comment: this gives you an array of 2 elements >  `rows = table.rows;` so your first for does not even run once

Comment: Just a thought, here; but rather than updating the DOM every time a row needs switched, would it not be more efficient to read the data that will determine the sort order into a two-dimensional array (or object), the other dimension being it's position in the table; use array.sort() and then write those to a document fragment in the correct order and then replace the node with the fragment? Or something along those lines, such that the DOM is not being adjusted for every row swap?

Comment: And the result of the observation of Anon is that the `while` loop condition remains true and, therefore, the loop never terminates.

Comment: @Anon if I console.log rows I get an htmlcollection of 553. however I'm rewriting code according to Gary's suggestion

Comment: @Gary code rewritten, it works. Thanks! I don't know how to manage this post now...will you write an answer-like so I can accept it or shall I ?

Comment: Glad it worked. Another suggestion might be to keep the data in the array between sorts, such that the data doesn't have to be read in from the DOM again.  That is, if the table content is static and the only difference is that the user keeps clicking different column headings to change the sort. If that works, then you could likely read the data as soon as the table loads so that the first sort is not delayed.. However, if there are many, many columns upon which to sort, it may be a lot to hold in RAM compared to reading only the column needed for each sort at each click.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Gary's advice I rewrote the function and now it works. I did some search and found out that the createDocumentFragment() method turns useful when dealing with large dataset as it is my case, so I've used it.

```
function sortTable(tableId, column) {
  const table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  const tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  const rows = Array.from(tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr"));
  // Extract the data into a two-dimensional array
  const rowData = rows.map((row) => {
    const cells = Array.from(row.getElementsByTagName("td"));
    return cells.map((cell) => cell.innerText);
  });
  rowData.sort((a, b) => {
    const aValue = a[column];
    const bValue = b[column];
    if (aValue < bValue) {
      return -1;
    } else if (aValue > bValue) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  // Create a new document fragment with the sorted rows
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
    const cells = rowData[i];
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.innerText = cells[j];
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    fragment.appendChild(row);
  }
  
  tbody.innerHTML = "";
  tbody.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Not trying to become annoying, here, and may already know this but there is a `replaceChildren()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) which ought to be `tbody.replaceChildren(fragment)`. Also, you could perhaps just [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the existing `tr` nodes rather than rebuilding them, such as `tbody.children[i].cloneNode(deep)` or something similar. It makes the code shorter but I don't know if it makes the background work any more efficient.